# Why does IE 11 crash when I open a page with applets in 64 bit jvm but works fine with 32 bit jvm?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet, 32bit-64bit, jniwrapper

I have a webpage that loads an applet. If I have 32 bit jre installed, everything works fine, but when I have only 64 bit jre, IE 11 crashes as soon as I open the page.

Also, when I keep both 32 and 64 bit then no matter what I keep in my environment variables, page loads but the applet is run by the 32 bit jvm even if I have not put its path anywhere.

Both 32 and 64 bit versions are same i.e 8u51.

I have also tried disabling all add-ons of IE, but no luck. There is no log generated nothing, so I don't know where to look.

The only reason I can think of is that there is some dll conflict. I am using JNI in the applet.

Also, why does it pick the 32 bit jvm by itself when I have not specified anywhere?

Comment: Side note: Applets are deprecated, and browsers are removing java support. Use Java Web Start instead, if you really need it.

Comment: I suspect it is because the browser is 32-bit, which in turn must load a 32-bit JVM into its self. It is not launching an external JVM.

Comment: I am afraid but I have to use applet. Also the browser is 64 bit. I have checked it.

Comment: Maybe the Applet you launch use JNI code that doesn't work properly in 64-bit environment and leads to the crash in MS IE?

Answer (score 0):

type navigator.platform in the dev tool console... it will tell you the bitness of the current IE frame. The File>Properties menu in IE will tell you which IE security zone the site is mapped to... By default only sites in the Trusted and Intranet Zones will use 32bit processes (ActiveX)... you should deploy both the 32bit and 64bit Java JRT to 64bit machines.... 32bit machines (of coarse) will only run 32bit processes, regardless of the IE security zone it is placed in...